# I have some code php wrong

Tags: php

I must be missing something obvious. I am new at this this. Line 55 in OSC validation which reads

```
if (preg_match()$mail_pat, $email, $components) {
```

produces the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/antony/public_html/osc/includes/functions/validations.php on line 55
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: You close `preg_match()` in the wrong place. Try `if (preg_match($mail_pat, $email, $components))`. If you had PHP warnings on, you'd be told that `preg_match()` expects at least 2 parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Just write

```
if (preg_match($mail_pat, $email, $components)) {
```

instead of

```
if (preg_match()$mail_pat, $email, $components) {
```

In fact, it's obvious...

Answer (score 4):

You must provide the arguments in the `preg_match` function.

`preg_match()` returns `1` if the pattern matches given subject, `0` if it does not, or `FALSE` if an error occurred.

So change your script line to this:

`if (preg_match($mail_pat, $email, $components)) {`

Answer (score 3):

What are you doing is absolute wrong. You should provide arguments to preg_match. You are not enclosing `$mail_pat, $email, $components` in the **preg_match()**. Just enclose variables in `**preg_match**` to make your code working

```
if (preg_match($mail_pat, $email, $components)) {
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

rechange your code to

```
if (preg_match($mail_pat, $email, $components))
```